# This content cannot be displayed in a frame - IE 8 - Facebook App

Tags: facebook, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have an iframe app but the links is throwing that error: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame". Only in IE 8. All the other browsers are fine. I read about the X-Frame-Options but I think I am not able to implement this. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Show us the code you are using, otherwise we have no idea what is going on.

Comment: I'm getting the same error why Robert Closed this?

Comment: I am also getting this problem when trying to display http://gk-architects.blogspot.com/ in an iframe.  It is independent of Facebook - seems to be an IE8 thing.